# How to find and delete duplicates in an user input in c#

Tags: c#, duplicates, code-duplication

I am trying to find duplicates from user inputs. I am trying to add customers with their first name, last name, and phone number. If all three of the information already exists, I want to throw an appropriate message saying {firstname}, {lastname}, and {phonenumber} already exists. Any idea how to do it?

//this code is on functions class.

```
public bool addCustomer(params)
{
    if (numCustomer < maxCustomer)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int id = rnd.Next(10000, 99999);
        clist[numCustomer] = new Customer(params);
        numCustomer++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

//Menu class to prompts user to choose an option

```
switch (input)
{
    case 1: // Add Customer
        Console.Clear();
        string fName;
        string lName;
        long phone;
        Console.WriteLine("Adding new customer...\nPlease enter the following:");
        Console.Write("First Name: ");
        fName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Last Name: ");
        lName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Phone Number (no dashes or spaces): ");
        phone = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());
        m.addCustomer(fName, lName, phone);
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to go back to the Customer Menu...");
        Console.ReadKey();
        customerMenu();
        break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you show us your code? is user a class and user inputs is a `List<User>`?

Comment: *Any idea how to do it?* - loads of them, but which one would be appropriate for your context will depend on what you have already. The code posted does not appear to ask for/know about customer first/last/number?

Comment: This is the code on the function class. In my main class, I have a switch case that prompts user to choose an entry. Whether add, delete, view customer

Comment: [No Attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). At a minimum, update the question to detail what you've tried and is not working.